# $error do no mutate in Vuelidate checkbox

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying out validate and having an issue as I want to check if my checkbox has `$error`, it will not submit the form. Upon outputting the $v I get the following but it doesn't change when I click. Basically, I have a big form and if it has $error set to true, it will not submit. I want to add `$error` to checkbox as well. [Code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxy9341xyj)

```
"form": {
    "checkbox": {
      "required": true,
      "$model": false,
      "$invalid": false,
      "$dirty": true,
      "$anyDirty": true,
      "$error": false,
      "$anyError": false,
      "$pending": false,
      "$params": {
        "required": {
          "type": "required"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With a checkbox, you need to use `sameAs`

```
  validations: {
    form: {
      checkbox: {
        sameAs: sameAs( () => true )
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `sameAs` isn't it things like "Password Confirmation"

Comment: We compare with `true`, mean that checkbox need to be checked

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom validator like this.

```
data(){
  checkbox_items: [],
  options: [
    { id: 1, label: 'label1' }
    { id: 2, label: 'label2' }
    { id: 3, label: 'label3' }
  ]
},
validations: {
  checkbox_items: {
    checked: value => {
      return value.length
    }
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div v-for="item in options" :key="item.id">
  <input type="checkbox"
    :id="'item.id"
    :class="{ error: $v.checkbox_items.$error }"
    :value="item.id"
    v-model="checkbox_items"
    @blur="$v.checkbox_items.$touch()">
  <label :for="'item.id">{{ item.label }}</label>
</div>
```